# Not able to access Field Values with a Dataset's FieldByName Method

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I have field value dataset 'EmployeeID' which has value '007' I want to assign it to one string variable 'EmployeeID' which is done by below code and value is copied to 'EmployeeID' variable successfully but I am not able to assign value from variable EmployeeID to dataset. Please help me.

```
String EmployeeID = Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString;
// Above line is working fine. Currently dataset field value is '007'

Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString = "";
```

Now i re - assign value to data set it still prints null.

```
Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString = EmployeeID;
```

Why. I want value again 007 in data set. How can I do that?

Comment: You question is C++ Builder, remove tag Delphi.

Comment: Done, Can you help me in above query? @fpiette

Comment: Maybe if you provide a complete minimal reproducible example showing your issue. Minimal means just the strict minimum and yet complete to demonstrate your issue. I'll then be able to check quickly without first trying to reproduce your problem myself. Follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString has value '007'

String EmployeeID = Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString;
//assigned value to new string variable. Now value of EmployeeID is 007.

 Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString = ""
//Cleared value from dataset.

Customers->FieldByName("EmployeeID")->AsString = EmployeeID;
//Re-assigning value to 007 but still getting null from dataset.
Why?
Can you now help me. i guess it's very clear now. @fpiette

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not just a scrap of code included in a comment.  It should be edited into your q (despite what has been said in another comment) and should be self-contained, in other words it should be possible for a reader to copy and paste it and then compile and run it so they can reproduce the problem on their own system.  I have voted to close this q until you do.

Comment: @Adityasharma: Yes, a [mre] is mandatory when asking questions about code that isn't working; it says so in the [help/on-topic] guidelines. When someone is trying to help you and asks for more information and you refuse, it does not encourage people to want to help you. Neither does your poor attitude. I'd suggest that you reconsider your conduct.

Answer (score 2):

Since you originally tagged your q `Delphi` and the dataset components are written in Delphi, I am posting a Delphi answer to your q.

Create a new console project and paste the code below into it:

```
program DatasetEdit;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Data.DB, DataSnap.DBClient;

var
  CDS : TClientDataSet;
  AField : TField;
  S : String;

begin
  try
    //  Create dataset and fields
    CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);

    AField := TIntegerField.Create(CDS);
    AField.FieldName := 'RecordID';
    AField.DataSet := CDS;

    AField := TStringField.Create(CDS);
    AField.FieldName := 'EmployeeID';
    AField.Size := 8;
    AField.DataSet := CDS;

    CDS.CreateDataSet;

    //  insert single record
    CDS.InsertRecord([1, '007']);

    S := CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString;
    writeln('S = ', S);

    //  attempt to change EmployeeID field
{.$define UseEdit'}
{$ifdef UseEdit}
    CDS.Edit;
{$endif}
    //  expect an exception here if `UsedEdit` is undefined
    CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString := '';

    writeln('EmploeyeeID is now ', CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString);

    CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString := S;

    writeln('EmploeyeeID is now ', CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString);

    //  don't leave CDS in dsEdit state
    CDS.Cancel;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  writeln('Press any key');
  readln;
end.
```

Compile the code and then single-step it in the debugger.  You should get an exception on the assignment to `CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString`.

> ---
>
> ### Debugger Exception Notification
>
> Project DatasetEdit.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Dataset not in edit or insert mode'.

Then, remove the dot from `{.$define UseEdit'}`, recompile and repeat the process.  This time, the code should execute correctly and produce the expected result, eventually restoring the saved value of `CDS.FieldByName('EmployeeID').AsString`.

The reason for this difference in behaviour is that the TDataSet class, on which all concrete TDataSet descendants are based, rigourously implements a state-machine (whose state is reflected in the dataset's `State` property), which ensures that the dataset is in the correct state for whatever operations are being undertaken.

In Data.DB, `TDataSetState` is defined as

```
  TDataSetState = (dsInactive, dsBrowse, dsEdit, dsInsert, dsSetKey,
    dsCalcFields, dsFilter, dsNewValue, dsOldValue, dsCurValue, dsBlockRead,
    dsInternalCalc, dsOpening)
```

Amongst other things, this state-machine requires the dataset to be in `dsEdit` or `dsInsert` state to permit the field contents to be changed.  The dataset enters these states by calls  to `Edit` and `Insert` respectively.  Navigation of the dataset, e.g. by calls to `First`, `Next`, `Last`, etc is only permitted when the dataset is in `dsBrowse` state.

Comment: Well, did this help you solve your problem?